# Sign windows-based SSH public key

Tags: windows, ssh

Does anybody successfully configured OpenSSH on Windows with CA signed host certificates? OpenSSH doesn't use this signed certificate in my case.

I tried:

1. Sign generated by OpenSSH public certificate sing Hashicorp Vault.
2. Issue certificate key pair with the same ssh engine in Vault.

In a both ways OpenSSH on Windows writes error: sshd: error: Public key for PROGRAMDATA/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key does not match private key.

ssh-keyscan from another host shows that Windows host returns short key which is not signed and dinamically generated based on private key

Comment: Hi seems you are not passing the pvt key, how are you trying to connect?

Comment: Hi! I don't need a private key to request public)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signed public keys should be named with "cert" at the end.
For example, ssh_host_ed25519_key-cert.pub.
Unfortunately, it's not clearly described in openssh docs. You can find it in ssh-keysign manual: https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keysign.8